# SOA with SOAP and REST implementation

Tags: soap, soa, restful-architecture

I am struggling with the concept SOA. Lets say there is a big project which contains a lot of specific business logic and resources. From what I've found SOAP and REST makes sense, SOAP for the business logic part and REST for the resources/CRUD part.

The idea that I have in mind is to use SOAP as a public entry-point and use the REST as an internal API for SOAP (because it should not have business logic), this way I can utilize the strength of both structures.

The problem here is that writing detail/overview requests will probably be in REST and SOAP services, which isn't good for maintenance.

Should mixing SOAP and REST be avoided or can they be used in the proper way of how I described it?

**EDIT** I will try to make a more specific case. I also came across a good article http://www.infoq.com/articles/tilkov-rest-doubts. Which will resolve a lot of problems with using business logic in REST, by renaming the models differently.

For example if you have an order with products and you have discount on it can be calculated after (creating) `POST`ing products to an */order* URL for example. And the discount is visible after `GET`ing the product on */order* URL. This fits perfectly in REST.

However when for some reason you can't have product *x* and *y* in the same order, this seems a bit difficult to do in a REST service. Because you will have to give proper error message like '*x* and *y* can't be in one order', this is exposing business logic and seems to fit better in SOAP. Is there a way to do this is REST and if so, is it better to do use REST in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A broad question, perhaps too broad.  Of course it depends on what you are building.  If you provide some more details, platform, targeting what kind of devices, etc you will get a better answer.

However, consider building RESTful api's for everything, public + internal.  I'd suggest checking out ServiceStack https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Why-Servicestack docs which discuss an approach for api's.  Even if you don't use their toolset, the concepts will help you build your own web api's.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have updated my question with some additional data. The platform has a lot of logic if you have x you can't do y and should do z.

Comment: Ok I have done something similar for a client with Vehicle configurators where they can add options to a vehicle.  Of course, some options depend on others, x must have y, some are mutually exclusive x must not be with y, and so on.  I have some server business layer enforce the rules and in my api I return the vehicle along with its last recent valid list of options and then a list of the "broken rules" detailing the options I could not add and the reasons why.  WCF or REST, its not the technology stopping you here - you can return anything you need in the message.